# How do I reset perspective for Eclipse e4 RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, perspective, e4

After building a perspective in application.e4xmi file, I am unable to reset perspective by calling IWorkbenchPage.resetPerspective().

Comment: You should write the question part as a question and put the answer as an answer. Then you can accept it yourself (which is totally fine!) after 24 Hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought this may save others some time, as well as document it for myself.

The trick to being able to reset an e4 perspective is as follows (assumes a basic application.e4xmi with PerspectiveStack element):

1. In your application.e4xmi file, locate your PerspectiveStack under your Application/TrimmedWindow node. Record/set its ID.
2. In Eclipse 4 Model Editor, drag your Perspective(s) from underneath your PerspectiveStack to Application/Snippets. (This will cause your perspective IDs to register with IPerspectiveRegistry, and provide a pristine state).
3. Create new CopyPerspectiveSnippetProcessor. This will copy the perspectives in your snippets to your PerspectiveStack on startup. This makes it so you don't have to maintain two copies of each perspective element in your e4xmi file.

   ```
   package com.example.application.processors;

   import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.MUIElement;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspective;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspectiveStack;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;

   /**
    * Copies all snippet perspectives to perspective stack called "MainPerspectiveStack" In order to register/reset perspective and not have to sync two copies in
    * e4xmi.
    * 
    */
   public class CopyPerspectiveSnippetProcessor {
       private static final String MAIN_PERSPECTIVE_STACK_ID = "MainPerspectiveStack";

       @Execute
       public void execute(EModelService modelService, MApplication application) {
           MPerspectiveStack perspectiveStack = (MPerspectiveStack) modelService.find(MAIN_PERSPECTIVE_STACK_ID, application);

           // Only do this when no other children, or the restored workspace state will be overwritten.
           if (!perspectiveStack.getChildren().isEmpty())
               return;

           // clone each snippet that is a perspective and add the cloned perspective into the main PerspectiveStack
           boolean isFirst = true;
           for (MUIElement snippet : application.getSnippets()) {
               if (snippet instanceof MPerspective) {
                   MPerspective perspectiveClone = (MPerspective) modelService.cloneSnippet(application, snippet.getElementId(), null);
                   perspectiveStack.getChildren().add(perspectiveClone);
                   if (isFirst) {
                       perspectiveStack.setSelectedElement(perspectiveClone);
                       isFirst = false;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Register your CopyPerspectiveSnippetProcess into your plugin.xml file.

   ```
   <extension id="MainAppModel" point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
       <processor beforefragment="false" class="com.example.application.processors.CopyPerspectiveSnippetProcessor"/>
   </extension>
   ```
5. Reset the perspective as normal. You will also want to set the perspective stack and the current perspective to visible, as these can sometimes be set to invisible. A sample handler might look like:

   ```
   import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspectiveStack;
   import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;
   import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

   public class ResetPerspectiveHandler {
       private static final String MAIN_PERSPECTIVE_STACK_ID = "MainPerspectiveStack";

       @Execute
       public void execute(EModelService modelService, MApplication application) {
            MPerspectiveStack perspectiveStack = (MPerspectiveStack) modelService.find(MAIN_PERSPECTIVE_STACK_ID, application);
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();
            perspectiveStack.getSelectedElement().setVisible(true);
            perspectiveStack.setVisible(true);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I added a test to prevent overwriting of persistent workspace state.

Comment: I have found that using this method can interfere with things like UI element dimension persistence, so beware this could have unacceptable side effects. We ended up being able to limit the UI such that it removed our requirement for perspective reset.

Comment: Using `PlatformUI` is not a proper solution for a pure e4 application.

Comment: Care to explain why not for anybody having similar issues? I don't really work in Java these days, so I don't have much context, but I do know E4 was quite new when I was working on this problem.

Comment: Using `PlatformUI` forces you to implement a lot "old" 3.x workbench bundle dependencies, which one normally tries to avoid setting up a pure e4 application. See V Kash Singh's answer for a correct "e4 way" (2nd approach in his code).

Answer (score 1):

Reset perspective (when you lunch e4 application without clearing work space, when you switch other perspective to your perceptive).

Step 1: Add a add-on in your model fragment at application level.
[image]

Step 2: Create Add-on class and implement EventHandler

Step 3: add following code in the class.

```
public class ResetPrespectiveAddOn implements EventHandler {

private static final String MY_PERSPECTIVE_ID = "myPrespectiveId";

@Inject
private IEventBroker broker;

@PostConstruct
public void loadPrespective() {

    broker.subscribe(UIEvents.ElementContainer.TOPIC_SELECTEDELEMENT, this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {

    //UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT is trigger  for all UI activity
    Object property = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT);
    if (!(property instanceof PerspectiveStackImpl)) {
        return;

    }

    // Reset perspective logic .
    IEclipseContext serviceContext = E4Workbench.getServiceContext();
    final IEclipseContext appContext = (IEclipseContext) serviceContext.getActiveChild();
    EModelService modelService = appContext.get(EModelService.class);
    MApplication application = serviceContext.get(MApplication.class);
    MWindow mWindow = application.getChildren().get(0);

    PerspectiveStackImpl perspectiveStack = (PerspectiveStackImpl) property;
    List<MPerspective> children = perspectiveStack.getChildren();
    for (MPerspective myPerspective : children) {
        if (myPerspective.getElementId().equals(MY_PERSPECTIVE_ID)) {

            //find active perspective
            MPerspective activePerspective = modelService.getActivePerspective(mWindow);
            if(activePerspective.getElementId().equals(MY_PERSPECTIVE_ID))

            //Reseting perspective  e3 way 
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();


            // till now there is no direct e4 way to reset perspective 
            // but u can Add and remove e4 perspective with this code code              
            EPartService partService = serviceContext.get(EPartService.class);
            MPerspectiveStack perspectiveStack = (MPerspectiveStack) (MElementContainer<?>) activePerspective.getParent();
            int indexOf = perspectiveStack.getChildren().indexOf(activePerspective);
            perspectiveStack.getChildren().remove(indexOf);

            perspectiveStack.getChildren().add(myPerspective);
            partService.switchPerspective(myPerspective);
        }   
    }
}}
```