# Can I inject IWorkbenchPage in Eclipse e4?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a handler which should reset perspective by using

```
@Execute
private void execute(IWorkbenchPage workbench) {
    workbench.resetPerspective();
}
```

However the function is never called due to unresolved argument. I believe the workbench is never injected. I'd like to know how can I fix this.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage` is part of Eclipse 3.x compatibility code and doesn't exist in a pure e4 application.

Comment: I tried to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717154/how-do-i-reset-perspective-for-eclipse-e4-rcp-application/20106360#20106360 however I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.`. What other option do I have ?

Comment: That answer is still using Eclipse 3.x compatibility code. If you are writing a pure e4 application it is not even clear what 'reset perspective' means. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24134818/2670892) looks closer to what you want

Comment: I am trying to reset the perspective to the original state (before resizing or closing). I am checking the question you mentioned now. Thanks